# Python: how assign list of values to pandas cells?

Tags: python, pandas

I want to assign to each cell of my pandas column some lists.

```
index= [0,1,2,3]
myvalues = [[43, 35], [37, 3, 29], [34, 90, 102, 23]]
myDF = pd.DataFrame(index=index)
myDF['column'] = [[] for _ in range(len(myDF))]
myDF.loc[[0,3], 'column'] = myvalues[0]
myDF.loc[1, 'column'] = myvalues[1]
myDF.loc[2, 'column'] = myvalues[2]
myDF

   column
0   43
1   [37, 3, 29]
2   [34, 90, 102, 23]
3   35
```

However I would like that `myDF.column[0] = myvalues[0] = [43, 35]` and `myDF.column[3] = myvalues[0] = [43, 35]`

In a more complex case I do,

```
infoData['cumCSchool'] = [[] for _ in range(len(infoData))] ## the column I want to change
for i,j in enumerate(df['name']):
    tmp = infoData[infoData['name']==j] ## info about a name
    some_list = list(tmp.index.values) ## list of the index I want to change
    val = list(df['cumCSchool'][i].values)
    infoData.loc[[some_list], 'cumCSchool'] = [val]
```

and I got the following error

```
"None of [Index([(0, 27, 68, 69, 71, 77, 82, 84, 92, 93, 107, 122, 140, 141, 149, 159, 188, 205, 224, 226, 231, 236, 261, 263, 270, 274, 289, 292, 293, 302, 313, 325, 330, 332, 336, 346, 347, 351, 357, 388, 421, 423, 430, 436, 448, 461, 483, 491, 501, 503, 517, 524, 525, 530, 562, 575, 582, 583, 599, 600, 602, 606, 617, 620, 630, 638, 640, 648, 649, 663, 673, 675, 679, 686, 689, 704, 705, 717, 720)], dtype='object')] are in the [index]"
```

Comment: let me know if my answer helps

Comment: @serafeim yes but not in my more complex case

Comment: what is the more complex case? I posted an answer based on your exact question

Comment: @serafeim yes and I accepted it.

Comment: You have not accepted the answer yet. just upvoted. but let me know about the complex case and I will edit my post

Comment: @serafeim I can accept it in 3 minutes. I will make another question, ok?

Comment: just modify your original add and add the complex case as well. no need to create a new question

Comment: @serafeim I added the description of the script. I am not sure it is easy to understand

Comment: it seems that this line: `some_list = list(tmp.index.values)` gives the error but i cannot help more without the data or some artificial data that cause this error

Comment: @serafeim the error is given by `infoData.loc[[some_list], 'cumCSchool'] = [val]`

Comment: can you post the `infoData ` dataframe with the data ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `myDF.loc[[0,3], 'column'] = [myvalues[0]]`:

```
index= [0,1,2,3]
myvalues = [[43, 35], [37, 3, 29], [34, 90, 102, 23]]
myDF = pd.DataFrame(index=index)
myDF['column'] = [[] for _ in range(len(myDF))]
myDF.loc[[0,3], 'column'] = [myvalues[0]]
myDF.loc[1, 'column'] = myvalues[1]
myDF.loc[2, 'column'] = myvalues[2]
myDF
```

Output:

```
              column
0           [43, 35]
1        [37, 3, 29]
2  [34, 90, 102, 23]
3           [43, 35]
```

Comment: it works in this example but not in my more complex case and I do not why